Single value constraints in PER encoding
My understanding is that the following statement in X.691 says that INTEGER types with single value constraints  will not encode anything.

13.2.1 If PER-visible constraints restrict the integer value to a single value, then there shall be no addition to the field-list, completing these procedures.

I also understand that nothing is encoded in the ASN.1 like below. and I tested it with asn1tools in python.
Num1 ::= INTEGER (40)

Input: Num1 = 40
Output: b'' (Empty bit string)

When using union for single value constraints, there is no guarantee that the value encoded will always be the same. However, with asn1tools in python, nothing is ever encoded.
Num2 ::= INTEGER (40 | 50 | 60)

Encoding:
  Input: Num2 = 40
  Output: b'' (Empty bit string)
  Input: Num2 = 50
  Output: b'' (Empty bit string)
  Input: Num2 = 60
  Output: b'' (Empty bit string)

Decoding:
  Input: b'' (Empty bit string)
  Output: 40

I had assumed that it would follow the ENUMERATED type encoding, but I didn't find a basis for that in X.691.
I'm wondering if it's correct that nothing is encoded in the above case, and if it's no longer a single value constraints when using a union.
Any help is appreciated.

This is a limitation of the tool you are using ...
If you try on https://asn1.io/ you'll find following results
Num2 ::= INTEGER (40 | 50 | 60)

Encoding:
  Input: Num2 = 40
  Output: b'00000000' (0x00 - No bits set)
  Input: Num2 = 50
  Output: b'01010000' (0x50)
  Input: Num2 = 60
  Output: b'10100000' (0xA0)

Thanks Paul for the explanation in the comments on how you get that from the X691 document ...
The range of the INTEGER is 60-40=20
"range" is less than or equal to 255 (the bit-field case), we need 5 bits
It requires the generation of a bit-field with a 5 bits containing the value ("n" – "lower bound") as a
non-negative-binary-integer encoding in a bit-field as specified in 11.3.
The bit field will contain 0 for the value 40, 10 for the value 50 and 20 for the value 60
So, you get the encoding of the 3 possible values for Num2

40: we encode 0 on 5 bits: 00000
50: we encode 10 on 5 bits: 01010
60: we encode 20 on 5 bits: 10100

You find the hex value above padding 3 bits set to 0

I didn't go and read X.691 very carefully so I don't want to say definitively that the tool is giving wrong encodings, but I think it is.  At a glance, that type should be encoded as a constrained whole number with a range of 60-40+1=21, and the value encoded is then relative to the lower bound (40).  I'm sure someone from OSS (the maker of that tool) will comment.

I just tried this on asn1.io, and the encoding for the value 40 is not b'', but 0x00 since the lower bound of the constraint is 40 which gets encoded as 0x00 since the lower bound is subtracted before the value is encoded.  Note that the range of constraint requires only the first 5 bits to encode the values.  This is why you see the 0x50 for 50 and 0xA0 for 60.

I edited YaFred's answer to more accurately reflect the result from the asn1.io website.

oups, thanks for fixing and thanks for the explanation

It would appear that when single value constraints are unioned, they should be encoded as a constrained whole number with the upper bound being the largest of the constraints and the lower bound being the smallest. I will be utilising the https://asn1.io/ that Prad kindly pointed out to me for further study of x.691. I would like to extend my gratitude to YaFred, Kevin and Paul for their answers.

Yes. Something to keep in mind is that the presence of a constraint does not presume it is PER encoded. So the union is used to validated the INTEGER value (40|50|60) but the PER visible constraint is actually (40..60)
